# How to insert data in list using class?

Tags: list, flutter, flutter-listview

***EDIT***

Thank you all for the kind comments.
This is strange, but yesterday, the emulator shows the red screen stated `type 'List<String>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Recyclable>' of 'function result'`. Somehow, when I rerun the emulator today to try another shot to fix the issue, it works fine! I will keep this post just in case anyone finds it useful, and thank you all again for your help!

***ORIGINAL POST***

I am trying to follow [the flutter official website](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/passing-data) to (1) create a `class`, (2) create a `list` using the `class`, (3) show the `list` using `ListView`. However, the terminal says that `type 'List<String>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Recyclable>' of 'function result'`. I have no idea why.

Here is my `class`:

```
class Recyclable {
  final String title;
  final String description;

  Recyclable(this.title, this.description);
}
```

Here is my `list`:

```
List<Recyclable> recyclable = [
  Recyclable('Plastic1', 'abc1'),
  Recyclable('Plastic2', 'abc2'),
  Recyclable('Plastic3', 'abc3'),
  Recyclable('Plastic4', 'abc4'),
  Recyclable('Plastic5', 'abc5'),
  Recyclable('Plastic6', 'abc6'),
];
```

Here is my `ListView`:

```
class _SearchPageState extends State<SearchPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Theme(
      data: LightThemeGrey(),
      child: DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: MyAppBar.getAppBar(context, Colors.black54, 'SEARCH'),
          //show background behind the app bar
          extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
          body: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 20, 0, 0),
            child: SafeArea(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: recyclable.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(recyclable[index].title),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Paste the output from console (terminal) too.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] including the compiler error and what line it is you get it on.

Comment: where is this function `result` defined?

Comment: I tested your code and it's working fine

Comment: Check this link out => [DartPad code works well](https://dartpad.dev/215ba63265350c02dfbd586dfd30b8c3). It is working fine. Run the code, and see for yourself :) There might be some other issues, just dig deep and you  will figure out